# How to select first history state in photoshop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have loaded an image in Photoshop, after editing some changes i need to save as this file, then I again hop on to the first history state i.e. that is image without editing and again do some changes and save it as other name. I need a script to hop on to the first history state so that I could start editing on the fresh image again and again.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You can use

doc.activeHistoryState = doc.historyStates[1];

This is really useful when you have to work on the same files again and again.